# how to trace guest OS when qemu is run with kvm enabled and cpu is host?

Tags: debugging, gdb, qemu, kvm, gdbserver

Is it possible to trace **guest OS** execution (break/watchpoints, single-stepping) when kvm is used and cpu is set to host?

If I run qemu with

> qemu-system-x86_64 -no-kvm -cpu core2duo -m 256 -cdrom kernel.iso -s -S
>
> target remote :1234     //on gdb commande line

tracing goes fine but when I run using

> qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -cpu host -m 256 -cdrom kernel.iso

no breakpoint works (guest never stops) so my question. If yes, can someone point me the right config?

I do need kvm to expose PMU features to the guest.

*PMU : Performance Monitoring Unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what i was missing.
With kvm enabled and cpu set to host, use hardware breakpoint instead of software breakpoint.
The only problem is that our budget in hardware breakpoint is limited

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is called: Virtual Machine Introspection (VMI).
Take a look at these two papers:

```
Virtual machine introspection: Techniques and applications

A Survey on Hypervisor Based Monitoring: Approaches, Applications, and Evolutions
```

Comment: Why not simply answer the question? This isn't in any case a response to the question